# How to find the record_Id((module-type-id and module-record-id) separated by (x)) for REST API in vTiger CRM

Tags: rest, vtiger, vtigercrm, dynamic-picklist-vtiger

So I want to use REST API for vTiger CRM. In that particular, I need to use the retrieve API to get the data of the deal.
So I need to mention the record_id, and then I can't find the record_id.
In the documentation, it is written that the record id combination of both (module-type-id and module-record-id) is separated by (x).
But also I can't find the module-type-id and module-record-id. Can someone please help me?

The link that we are using for vTiger Rest api is:
https://help.vtiger.com/article/147111249-Rest-API-Manual

So in this link, in order to fetch the data, we need to get the record id. And we are unable to find the record id. Can someone help me in finding the record id?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rest api uses a composite key to represent record id, a combination of (module-type-id and module-record-id) separated by (x).

module record id:
It is located in the URL of the webpage under the parameter id.

Module type id:

Module Name ID number

Account 3

Assets  27

Calendar    1

Campaigns   17

Cases   39

CampanyDetails  26

Contacts    4

Currency    21

DocumentFolders 22

Documents   7

EmailCampaigns  37

Emails  8

Events  18

Faq 10

Groups  20

HelpDesk    9

Invoice 16

Leads   2

LineItem    33

ModComments 28

Olark   40

PBXManager  24

Potentials  5

PriceBooks  12

PrintTemplates  41

Products    6

ProductTaxes    35

Project 31

ProjectMilestone    29

ProjectTask 30

PurchaseOrder   14

Quotes  13

SalesOrder  15

ServiceContracts    23

Services    25

SLA 38

Tax 34

Users   19

Vendors 11

Answer (score 0):

You can use the "describe" operation to get that sort of information:

`GET /webservice.php?operation=describe&sessionName=sessionId&elementType=<TYPE> HTTP/1.1`

Where `elementType` is the name of the module you want to retrieve information from. It could be `Contacts`, `Accounts`, etc. If you want to know the name of a particular module just navigate to that module in Vtiger and take a look at the url. There is a query parameter called `module`.

See here for more information: https://code.vtiger.com/vtiger/vtigercrm-manual/wikis/Webservice-Docs

Comment: We are following another link : https://help.vtiger.com/article/147111249-Rest-API-Manual

In this in order to get the deal information we need the record id. And that's what we are looking for.

Comment: are you using vtiger open source or vtiger cloud?

Comment: I am using vTiger CRM.

Comment: yes, but there is the open source version and the cloud version.

Comment: Cloud version. But thanks for helping, I had found the way to the answer.